# Changing whether the footer rule is present

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, rules

I would like the footer to be different after the first page of my problem sheet document

I have implemented the following:

```
\fancypagestyle{questions}
{
    \fancyhf{}% Delete the current section for header and footer
%    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
    \lhead{\rightmark}
    \rhead{\ifnumequal{\value{page}}{1}{Date:\hspace{2cm}}{}}
    \lfoot{\ifnumequal{\value{page}}{1}{MDW, \the\year}{}}
    \rfoot{\ifnumequal{\value{page}}{1}{\printmark{}}{}}
    \ifnumequal{\value{page}}{1}{\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}}{\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}
}
```

and it all works apart from the footer rule which always persists beyond the first page.

I would be very grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Your test for the page number is only applied for where you declare the page style that you want.  It's not reprocessed for every page.

There are various work arounds.  Here's one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\newcommand{\setupFooter}{%
  \ifnum\value{page}=1\relax
    \gdef\footrulewidth{0.4pt}%
  \else
    \gdef\footrulewidth{0pt}%
  \fi
}
\fancypagestyle{questions}
{
    \fancyhf{}% Delete the current section for header and footer
    \lhead{\rightmark\setupFooter}
    \rhead{\ifnumequal{\value{page}}{1}{Date:\hspace{2cm}}{}}
    \lfoot{\ifnumequal{\value{page}}{1}{MDW, \the\year}{}}
    \rfoot{\ifnumequal{\value{page}}{1}{}{}}
}
\pagestyle{questions}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

Comment: @egreg Why the change from `\ifnum\thepage` to `\ifnum\value{page}`?  Are they not equivalent?

Comment: No, they're not; `\thepage` is the output representation and can be alphabetical, Roman or even something else. To the contrary, `\value{page}` is always an integer number that pleases `\ifnum`.